# how to call c# code from javascript in phonegap windows phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, cordova

Hi Iam windows phone fresher.Can anyone tell me how to call C# methods in javascript in Phonegap(windows mobile).Thank you.

Iam getting the following error.

error: "Unable to locate command :: MyCommand".

This is my code Behind file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using WP7CordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
namespace CSharpToJS
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GapBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
namespace WP7GapClassLib.PhoneGap.Commands
{
    public class MyCommand : BaseCommand
    {
        public void DoThis(string args)
        {
            // TODO: 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-    scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cordova WP7</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // once the device ready event fires, you can safely do your thing! -jm
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.getElementById("welcomeMsg").innerHTML += "Cordova is ready! version=" + window.device.cordova;
        console.log("onDeviceReady. You should see this message in Visual Studio's output window.");
        var args = { "message": "whatever" };
        Cordova.exec(null, null, "MyCommand", "DoThis", args);
    }
  </script>
 </head>
  <body>
 <h1>
    Hello Cordova</h1>
<div id="welcomeMsg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't confuse Java with Javascript :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using the [plugin architecture](http://www.risingj.com/archives/tag/plugins) and the `PhoneGap.exec()` method.

Create a class in c# that inherits from BaseCommand (you must also use this specific namespace):

```
namespace WP7GapClassLib.PhoneGap.Commands
{
    public class MyCommand : BaseCommand
    {
      public void DoThis(string args)
      {
        // TODO: 
      }
    }
}
```

Call this method from Javascript:

```
var args = {"message":"whatever"};    
PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "MyCommand", "DoThis", args);
```

Comment: Hi Johansson,thank you and I tried with the above code but it is giving the error like "phonegap is undefined",shall i do any changes?

Comment: Iam getting error by trying this code,can u pls explain me the above code y i got the error?thanks in advance

Comment: Have you used that exact namespace?

Comment: yah,eventhough it is giving error.do i need to make any external changes?thank you.

Comment: Then you probably haven't defined args before calling the method. This is basic stuff. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Johansson,again iam getting error like "Unable to locate command :: MyCommand".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Notify method inconjunction with the ScriptNotify event handler, as detailed in the following blog post :-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/glengordon/archive/2011/11/21/phonegap-on-wp7-tip-2-script-interaction.aspx